# Open REST API for PLM

Tags: java, oracle-agile-plm

I want to write a JAR, which will be helpful in fetching data from PLM(Bug management tool). but i am not find any API for this.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should use the Agile API – A Java API with interfaces that expose Agile business objects. Please use the links below to refer.

```
Oracle Agile Software Development Kit (SDK)
Oracle Agile Web Services
Oracle Agile Integration Services (AIS)
```

http://www.willdosoft.com/oracle-agile-plm-integration/
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/agileplm-sample-520945.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Agile SDK or AIS. Agile SDK provides access to the PQM objects such as PSR's and QCR's that you can use to manipulate the data. You can also use AIS or Export service to get the data out of Agile.